# pandas: Изображение множественных графиков

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Есть подобная структура данных:

| g1 | g2 | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | c | 1 | 5 |
| A | c | 2 | 6 |
| A | c | 3 | 7 |
| A | c | 4 | 8 |
| A | d | 1 | 6 |
| A | d | 2 | 6 |
| A | d | 3 | 5 |
| A | d | 4 | 7 |
| B | c | 5 | 7 |
| B | c | 3 | 1 |
| B | c | 4 | 2 |
| B | c | 2 | 3 |
| B | d | 5 | 6 |
| B | d | 3 | 2 |
| B | d | 4 | 3 |
| B | d | 2 | 2 |

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'g1': list('A'*8+'B'*8), 
                   'g2': list('c'*4+'d'*4+'c'*4+'d'*4), 
                   'x': list('1234'*2+'5342'*2), 
                   'y': list('5678665771236232')})
```

Как без создания новых DF или столбцов построить линейные графики по группам из `g1` и `g2` на одной `figure`, с использованием метода `DataFrame.plot`? (с разной окраской, чтобы понять, что к чему)

Пробовал группировать, а потом `unstack`'ать в столбцы, но не ясно, как правильно указать, чтобы получить желаемое.

```
GB = DF.groupby(['g1', 'g2', 'x']).mean()
US = GB.unstack(level=['g1','g2'])
```

Пример ожидаемого результата:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/itt1w4eagt

Comment: Во время группировки вы все равно получаете датафрейм. вот его колонки и выводите на график: `grouped_df.plot(x='col_name_1', y='col_name_2')`. А вообще, работайте напрямую с ООП matplotlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, если у вас есть желание что-то вывести из датафрейма всроенными методами на одну фигуру, то делаете так:

```
ax = df.plot()
# затем, при построении каждого графика добавляйте в plot аргумент `ax=ax`
df.plot(ax=ax)
```

Но я бы советовал работать напрямую с matplotlib, поскольку для более сложных построений так будет лучше:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l=[]
for i, g in df.groupby(['g1', 'g2']):
    g = g.sort_values('x')
    ax.plot(g['x'],g['y'])
    l.append(i)

ax.legend(l)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во 1, группировка должна давать не такие группы, а Ac, Ad, Bc, Bd. Во 2, график не то, что ожидается (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/itt1w4eagt  (температура цвета обозначает принадлежность к группе A или B))

Comment: Во-первых, не нужно писать "во 1 и во 2" - это не по-русски; во-вторых, вы должны четко формулировать вопрос, чтобы было ясно, что вы хотите получить; в-третьих, у вас в ожидаемом графике данные отсортированы по `x`, а в оригинальном датасете - нет; в-четвертых, я поправил ответ.